# Xcode 9.4.1 when upload App Store Missing App Store Icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9.4

We have a problem. We are working on a long time.
We get an error when uploading to the app store. This problem started to happen after xcode update 8.3.3 -> 9.4.1 .

The main problem, WARNING ITMS-90704: "Missing App Store Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format.
Can you help me?

Comment: you have not set app icon in Assets

Comment: go to Assets and there you can see the option for adding AppIcon. There you can add the app icon

Comment: I added 1024*1024 png icon. I'm sure. I checked several times.

Comment: you must add the icon for all slots with the required size. For example, if iPhone notification require 20pt icon, in 2x slot you must add 2 * 20 pt icon size such as 40pt icon.

Comment: Make sure you added it in itunesconnect.apple.com well

Comment: I tried all of them.

Comment: I tried everything and i finally solved. This problem started to happen after xcode update 8.3.3 -> 9.4.1.. Xcode 9.4.1 open and open a new project. Create new assets catalog. Fill in the required icons correctly. This AppIcon catalog right click and show in finder,open AppIcon.appiconset folder and copy all things in folder. Open old project,old project AppIcon catalog right click and show in finder and open folder delete all things. Paste in the folder you copied. Clean, Build Project and Archive. And Succesfully Upload App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Goto `Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon -> Set icon for Appstore(1024*1024)`

[image]

Comment: App Store iOS already not null. But when upload to App store always fail.

Comment: I checked several times. Appstore icon size 1024*1024.

Comment: I dont fully understand. Sorry. Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks for explain. I checked itunesconnect but there is nothing.

Comment: and whats the extension of your icon?

Comment: icon extension png

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the App icon of 1024*1024 for the app store, which must be without alpha.